# Move absolutely positioned element behind absolutely positioned parent

Tags: css

I have 2 elements one inside the other. Both elements are absolutely positioned. I want to move the child element behind its parent.

HTML:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.parent{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background: #000;
    z-index: 2;
}

.child{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 90%;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: yellow;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Here is a fiddle to edit and test: https://jsfiddle.net/v7fdeygm/

I want to move the small yellow box behind its black box parent.

**I can't use negative `z-index` values because both elements are clickable.**

Is this possible?

Comment: Why don't you just take the `z-index` off `.parent`? Then you can set `z-index: -1` on `.child`.